# Webdriver is not capturing the http response body

Tags: selenium, logging, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

I have enabled the PERFORMANCE logging in my Chrome WebDriver. Its capturing request and response traffic. But the body of the response is missing, capturing only headers, timing info. Response type is `Fetch`

```
selenium-java version : 3.6
Driver version : selenium/standalone-chrome:3.8.1
```

Code snippet is like this,

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
LoggingPreferences logPref = new LoggingPreferences();
logPref.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPref);

Map<String, Object> perfLogPrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
perfLogPrefs.put("enableNetwork", true);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("perfLoggingPrefs", perfLogPrefs);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, getCapabilities())
```

Response is like this

```
    Network.responseReceived {
   "frameId": "(5E32E9E7FBF69A4DB1EA649C671E1840)",
   "loaderId": "(47DA896570956A7238312B7A044024D7)",
   "requestId": "4857.105",
   "response": {
      "connectionId": 548,
      "connectionReused": true,
      "encodedDataLength": 47,
      "fromDiskCache": false,
      "fromServiceWorker": false,
      "headers": {
         "atl-vtm-backend-time": "1670",
         "atl-vtm-queue-time": "0",
         "atl-vtm-time": "1670",
         "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
         "cde-service": "billing-ux-service",
         "cde-target": "https://billing-ux-service.staging.io",
         "cde-type": "DEFAULT",
         "content-length": "603",
         "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
         "date": "Wed, 14 Feb 2018 04:58:52 GMT",
         "expires": "0",
         "pragma": "no-cache",
         "status": "200",
         "strict-transport-security": "max-age=315360000; includeSubDomains; preload",
         "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
         "x-frame-options": "DENY",
         "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
      },
      "mimeType": "application/json",
      "protocol": "h2",
      "remoteIPAddress": "104.192.142.74",
      "remotePort": 443,
      "requestHeaders": {
         ":authority": "test-1518577270615-208.dev.com",
         ":method": "GET",
         ":path": "/admin/rest/billing-ux/api/billing/bill-estimate",
         ":scheme": "https",
         "accept": "application/json",
         "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
         "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
         "content-type": "application/json",
         "cookie": "blah-blah",
         "referer": "https://test-1518577270615-208.dev.com/admin/billing/applications?chrome=false&react=false",
         "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36"
      },
      "securityDetails": {
         "certificateId": 0,
         "cipher": "AES_128_GCM",
         "issuer": "DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA",
         "validFrom": 1469404800,
         "validTo": 1534507200
      },
      "securityState": "secure",
      "status": 200,
      "statusText": "",
      "timing": {
         "connectEnd": -1,
         "connectStart": -1,
         "dnsEnd": -1,
         "dnsStart": -1,
         "proxyEnd": -1,
         "proxyStart": -1,
         "pushEnd": 0,
         "pushStart": 0,
         "receiveHeadersEnd": 1963.64500001073,
         "requestTime": 407491.206811,
         "sendEnd": 0.937999982852489,
         "sendStart": 0.484999967738986,
         "sslEnd": -1,
         "sslStart": -1,
         "workerReady": -1,
         "workerStart": -1
      },
      "url": "https://test-1518577270615.208-dev.com/admin/rest/billing-ux/api/billing/bill-estimate"
   },
   "timestamp": 407493.170997,
   "type": "Fetch"
}
```

Comment: did you solve it out?

Comment: any luck solving this ?

Comment: Selenium is not supporting this. I have solved it by using some proxy it between.